# Generate post-processed xml in Sandcastle?

Tags: sandcastle, xml-documentation

There are some features like `inheritdoc` which are not supported natively by Visual Studio. How to convert input xml file with unsupported tags to its post-processed version so it can be included into release package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Intellisense Only` plugin should do the job for you. You can find it under project properties in plugins tab (see [Intellisense plugin doc](https://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/1fcdf9d3-06fb-4a7b-a584-f55b6ea5baae.htm)).